# Caching POST: What are appropriate headers?

Tags: jquery, ajax, http, post

From [RFC 2616](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2616.html), section 9.5 (POST):

> Responses to this method are not cacheable, unless the response includes appropriate Cache-Control or Expires header fields.

What are *appropriate headers*?

Background: The server responds with the following headers, and I am worried that the response may be cached. Example response headers:

```
Cache-Control:max-age=2592000, public
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:22
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Sun, 20 May 2012 13:46:06 GMT
Expires:Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=15, max=100
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache/2.2.22 (Amazon)
Vary:Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.3.13
```

The post request is made from JavaScript using jQuery's `$.ajax` function with `cache` set to `false`. However, jQuery ignores that option. Quote from its [documention as of 2012-05-20 CEST](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post):

> Pages fetched with POST are never cached, so the cache and ifModified options in jQuery.ajaxSetup() have no effect on these requests.

### Update

Could it be that jQuery's documentation is wrong? See my [related thread in the jQuery forum](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/shouldn-t-post-respect-cache-option#14737000003393023).

Answer (score 1):

This header,

```
Cache-Control:max-age=2592000, public
```

Will cause the response to be cached by any intermediary for a long time.  The response is a bit confused because `pragma: no-cache` contradicts this.  However, I would suspect that it is only certain older proxies that would even look at the pragma header.

jQuery has no control over intermediary caches so there may exist some public cache, at your ISP for example, that is caching the response.

Comment: So jQuery is wrong in *not* adding a random string to the URL for POST requests that should not be cached? (it does that for GET requests)

Answer (score 0):

Seems confusing, `Cache-Control` looks like enabling cache, while `Pragma` and `Expires` seems to disable cache at the same time. Anyway, HTTP status code should tell exactly whether the request was cached or not. `200` - not cached, `304` or similar - cached.